# Angular 4 form submit is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I am using Angular 4 for my application development. When I submit my form it's calling the browser URL for posting.
 Browser showing something like this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>
The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
</Message>
<Method>POST</Method>
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
<RequestId>EDFDF7D3C3D38F</RequestId>
<HostId>
adasdsa$623y234
</HostId>
</Error>
```

My form and code:

```
 <form #loginForm="ngForm" method="post" (ngSubmit)="login()">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg sample@gmail.com " name="emailids" [(ngModel)]="emailid" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$" required #emailids="ngModel">
<input type="{{pswdInputType}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password here" name="userpassword" [(ngModel)]="userPassword"
                                    required #userpassword="ngModel">

                            <button [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn_submit mt_20 hvr-icon-forward"></button>
                        </form>
```

Login function :

```
  login() {
      this._loginService.login(this.emailid, this.userPassword).subscribe(res => {
console.log("success")
      }, error => {
        this.toastr.error('User  not found!', null, { toastLife: 2000 });
      });
}
```

I don't know what's the issue happening here. It's not calling the login function instead of this function call the form POST method is trying to 
post the browser url (www.example.com/login)
Registration also have save form structure there also facing same issue

Please suggest!!

I am really stuck in this issue Please help

Comment: try removing method="post"

Comment: removed method="post"  but still it's not calling the login function

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: no errors showing in console its directly showing error in browser page. That's I already added in my question

Comment: I think you missed to define and pass these: `this.emailid, this.userPassword` in/to the `login()` function as parameter, and then when invoking it in the form tag using eventBinding `(ngSubmit)="login()"` you have also to get them from your form fields and pass them to `login()`. E.g. `(ngSubmit)="login(emailids.value, userpassword.value)"`. Give it a try and check the Console/Network.